# OneNote Api - copyToNotebook hanging

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

The OneNote-Api recently started to hang on this call:

```http
https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/me/notes/sections/{id}/copyToNotebook
```

Polling the result (as always) now returns the following

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/$metadata#me/notes/operations/$entity",
    "id": "copy-645387ea-eb06-4a0d-bcde-09d276e4e3d6fe0e14f6-3e53-421e-aa6c-8adcc998a4dd",
    "status": "not started",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-10-04T16:57:45.9599909Z",
    "lastActionDateTime": "2017-10-04T16:57:45.9599909Z"
}
```

The `lastActionDateTime` never updates and the command doesn't complete despite returning the correct `202` code and subsequent `200` codes.

Any help would be appreciated (especially in a live working environment)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the API correctly - we introduced a problem in our service a couple of days ago. This should be fixed now.

Thanks for reporting this. Feel free to report anything to us at: https://twitter.com/onenotedev?lang=en.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I'll hit twitter next time an issue crops up. Cheers Steve

Answer (score 0):

I performed the same operation and got back the same response. When checking my account to verify the copying worked I get back an error. 
JSON object returned below. The copy file seems to be corrupted on OneNotes side.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

```
{Responses: [[6,…]]}
Responses
:
[[6,…]]
0
:
[6,…]
0
:
6
1
:
{OperationId: 1, StatusCode: 126, RawCellStorageErrorCode: "InternalError.4", ServerPageStatsTrace: "",…}
AvailableFileAccess
:
1
CellId
:
"40c4a0be-3ff1-49c7-b169-ba9d74e0724c|1"
ContentBytes
:
0
ContextId
:
"null"
FileId
:
"WOPIsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fwopi%2Eonedrive%2Ecom%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F1438AEF7B187116%21122&access_token=4wfG%2D4rgaZ6xmefLfMpPpnlTOOxmBy0LNKwftRv4WQeE1YRkcD72ADoSfR%2DC2ZxSi11DuWIEGx0iSqZb8JP88aA36k2o8KKqF1hPyoFTblc3TyLt6k65eXe%2DL7QEcINnMhnvAA9aeuP5W2ttwIYE6dDJQVh9xkv5JcUndBG1d%5F3Ldp3%2DlcE3gNO7IEZtvzf7B0mUkKoerjtJr3OBKxsQzHx1PRCfh99BtCNPNvVVAq91thnpmeuVOATVGgWlMWcHTt29l9a8%2DrbHa3jknZWee6F6DBxU%5FzgW7YpWbZ4LtW1zOx33SQVm3XjRQ628TsgAV7%5Fy%2DJ4IvxCnGMVhpwvC%2DXLGnP35DAJW7LuetWKJ93B%5Fs&access_token_ttl=1510611198523"
OperationId
:
1
RawCellStorageErrorCode
:
"InternalError.4"
RevisionList
:
[]
RootCellId
:
"null"
ServerPageStatsTrace
:
""
StatusCode
:
126
```